# cURL RTSP Download

Tags: php, curl, rtsp

I'm trying to download .3gp videos online but the URL for these videos starts with rtsp://

Is it possible to use cURL to download these videos? I can't find anything about it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PHP cURL documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php), the PHP implementation of cURL supports libcurl.  According to the [curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), rtsp is supported.  That said, it appears to be new, as the [source code](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/rtsp.html) is dated this year.  Caveat: I don't have access to cURL or PHP where I am, so cannot test this.